# Histogram x-axis showing wrong range

Tags: r, histogram

I'm making a histogram from a column in a csv with values ranging from 100,000 to 10,000,000 and yet when I the data into r and make a histogram from that column the x-axis is all messed up, showing extremely large range when the largest value is 10,000,000.

This is where the dataset is from:
https://www.kaggle.com/kmldas/hr-case-study

This is the code I use to make the histogram:

```
hist(study_sample$Annual.Salary)
```

[image: SS]

Comment: 10,000,000 = 10^7 = 1e+07, right? It looks correct to me.

Comment: Based on the limited data that I can see, that x axis range and the histogram itself look like they are probably right. Of course, without any data to work with it's hard to know...an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Have you tried adjusting the bins to provide more resolution?

Comment: @BillO'Brien Yeah you're right, but is there any way to make it a bit more friendly to the person reading? Maybe showing the 10,000,000 number

Comment: There's an art to tweaking histograms. But you're looking at 3 orders of magnitude based on the data I can see in the screenshot. You could try a log transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable scientific notation in R with:

```
options(scipen = 999)
hist(HR_Case_Study$`Annual Salary`)
```

[image]

Head of data:

```
structure(list(Name = c("Aarti Panchal", "Aastha Behl", "Abhinaw Sinha", 
"Abhishek Dabb", "Abhishek Kumar Preetam", "Addi Studdeard"), 
    Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"
    ), Department = c("CEO", "Sales", "Engineering", "Legal", 
    "Support", "Support"), `Annual Salary` = c(10000000, 880500, 
    682200, 563700, 1070900, 1084500), Location = c("Mumbai", 
    "Bengaluru", "Bengaluru", "New Delhi", "New Delhi", "Mumbai"
    ), Rating = c("Very Good", "Very Good", "Good", "Very Good", 
    "Poor", "Poor"), `Distance to Office` = c(25, 7, 15, 5, 10, 
    6), Age = c(31, 40, 28, 39, 26, 38), `Tenure in Company` = c(10.4, 
    18.2, 6.6, 13.3, 4.8, 6.7)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```